# Searched Data Not Being Displayed

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to put a `search button` on my website where, if the user search for the *date* all the data from the db that have that "certain date" will be displayed. But for some reason, the datas are not displaying. Can you guys help me figure this out?

Below are my codes for the `search`

```
<form action="file.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD">
    <input type="submit" name="sub" value="Search Data">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_GET['sub'])){
    $search=$_GET['search'];

    $search_q="SELECT * FROM table WHERE date='$search'";
    $run_q=mysqli_query($con, $search_q);

    while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($run_q)){
        $date_q=$rows['date'];
        $impact_q=$rows['impact'];
        $advice_q=$rows['advice'];
        $typhoon_q=$rows['typhoon'];
        $warning_q=$rows['warning'];
?>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $date_q; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $impact_q; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $advice_q; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $typhoon_q; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $warning_q; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<?php } } ?>
```

Comment: Use error reporting. Don't just pass user input to SQL, parameterize. Is `table` your real table name? `$search-$_GET['search']` looks like a typo.

Comment: is it a typo? `$search-$_GET['search'];` shouldn't it be `$search=$_GET['search'];`

Comment: Is that typo in the real code or a copying error?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I fixed it already but the datas are still not displaying.

Comment: Your doing a post not a get use $_POST.

Comment: Whew! That fixed it! Thank you so much @JasonK

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and ideally should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 0):

You used method type `POST` for your search form. But you are receiving form data using `GET`. So please receive the form data using `$_POST`. Replace `$_GET['sub']` to `$_POST['sub']` and `$_GET['search']` to `$_POST['search']`.

Also please check your database table name. Did you give your table name: `table`?